# calling python script from another directory while working in pycharm

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm

I have following folder structure

Directory - **/srv/local/project/code/toolutil**

Sub Directory -

**toolutil/ui**

**toolutil/code**

**toolutil/database**

My present working script is located in **toolutil/code/setup.py** now i want to  call functions from python script which is located in this folder structure **"toolutil/database/work.py"** inside my present working script.

I want to build my codes in pycharm by calling script which is located in different location.
............................

Current Working File in pycharm IDE

File Location - /srv/local/project/code/toolutil/code/setup.py

```
#current working script location - /srv/local/project/code/toolutil/code/setup.py'

import os
import 'file i want to import /srv/local/project/code/databasr/work.py' as base

def follow():
    job = os.getenv("ENTITY") 

    # FUNCTION I WANT TO CALL FROM IMPORTED SCRIPT FROM DIFFERENT LOCATION

    struc = base.executeStructure()
    print struc
```

Comment: Note: it is bad practice, in Unix (other OSs are just bad practice), to name your executable with a file extension: this is because, if you change the language it is written in, then you have to change the filename, and all other scripts that call it.

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried?

Comment: Hi ctrl-alt-delor
I have edited the question with code hope you are getting me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, some how I figured out the solution 
we have to insert the path at '0' so imported module will get first priority in execution

```
import sys
sys.path.insert('0','/srv/local/project/code/databasr') #path of python script directory
import work as base #name of the python script
def follow():
    job = os.getenv("ENTITY")
    struc = base.executeStructure() #function inside module
    print struc
```

There is still one issue with pycharm is when we import module with sys.path.append/insert it doesn't show module functions pop up while working in pycharm. Don't know it's happening in my system or it's global problem but if we know the functions of imported module then we can work smoothly.